# Update errors Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, dpkg, plymouth

For a while after using the update manager, each time I get a message saying "the installation or removal of a software package failed." When using a lot of apt-get commands I also get an error similar to:

```
Setting up plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1) ...
sed: can't read /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth.in: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
    plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

At the end. How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance. If any other output tests need to be done I'd be happy to do so.

Comment: Have you tried a `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text`? Give me a ping with @A.B.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-install `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text` by running the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
sudo apt-get install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Hopefully, that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First try the commands below

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
```

---

If the error persists, follow the next steps

1. Open the file `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text.postinst` in an editor

   ```
   sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text.postinst
   ```
2. Search this code, should be start at line 21

   ```
   sed -re \
           "/\[ubuntu-text\]/ {
                   N;
                   s/(title=Ubuntu ).*\$/\1$(lsb_release -rs)/
           }" /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth.in \
                   > /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth
   ```
3. Add an `#`  before each line

   ```
   # sed -re \
   #        "/\[ubuntu-text\]/ {
   #                N;
   #                s/(title=Ubuntu ).*\$/\1$(lsb_release -rs)/
   #        }" /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth.in \
   #                > /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth
   ```
4. Save the file
5. Start the command below

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
   ```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and none of the solutions worked until I found it on the ubuntu forum in French, solution provided by "f.x0":

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text.postinst

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update
```

hope this helps!